# Google analytics two calls on pageview

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have implemented analytics with google tag manager on my website.
Can anybody explain,why there are two calls on Pageview?

First, one is for pageview, what this second call do?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the Google Tag Manager debugger? Are you seeing duplicate page views in Google Analytics?

Comment: No, I am not seeing duplicate pages in Analytics. if you look closely into the attached image both calls are not same for one page

Answer (score 2):

Since the name of the page was visible (now edited out) in the image I had a look at it. There are two pageviews configured within GTM. On is configured to override the page path, that's why the two calls are different (and why you do not see duplicates in GA).

It looks like somebody tried to implement [virtual pageviews](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#modifying_page_urls) (since this is a one page application without proper urls) and accidentally sends one pageview to many on the inital pageload.

Comment: I have just noticed on new page, it is sending my old page again in GA.
Can you please explain this. Is it also due to virtual pageviews in GTM interface or I have something to do at code level?

Comment: And yes it is one page application

Comment: Since this is implemented via GTM you need to go through your rules and see which one fires two analytics tags. I don't think it is possible to find the problem from the outside, this seems like a configuration glitch in GTM.

Comment: Can you please remove site name from your answer. This is really important.
and thank you for your help